# Kotlin: extend a dynamically given supertype

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

Suppose I have the classes:

```
class A : SuperType() {}

class B : SuperType() {}

class C : B() {}
```

Suppose I don't want `C` to extend `B()` anymore: I want it to extend `A()`, but now I want `A` to extend `B()`.

How can I make, on compile-time, `A` extend `B()` (or any child of `SuperType()`) instead of only `SuperType()`? In other words, how can I make class `A` declaration generic to accept any child of `SuperType()`?

Hope it was clear. I'd like to do something like:

```
class B(whatever_it_receives_as_long_as_child_of_SuperType) : whatever_it_receives_as_long_as_child_of_SuperType()

class C : A(B())    // B is subtype of SuperType so it's ok
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make, on compile-time, A extend B() (or any child of SuperType()) instead of only SuperType()?

You can't. Each class can only extend one fixed superclass.

I think the closest you can get is

```
class A(x: SuperType): SuperType by x
```

(See [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#implementation-by-delegation)) but this requires `SuperType` to be an interface instead of a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
open class SuperType {}
open class A(val obj: SuperType) : B() {}
open class B : SuperType() {}
class C : A(B())
```

or using generics:

```
open class SuperType {}
open class A<T: SuperType>(val obj: T) : B() {}
open class B : SuperType() {}
class C : A<B>(B())
```